# Printing an integer array in java using for loop, but the first element is always zero

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, integer

I have been trying for hours to change a user inputted string of numbers into an integer, then create and print an integer array with those integers. I finally got it, but the first element of the printed array is always zero. I don't know how to fix it. I feel like it is really simple, but I am exhausted and am getting stuck on the easiest things. Does anyone know what is wrong? I'll put my code below.

```
String stringNum = input.nextLine();
int size = stringNum.length();
int[] myArray = new int[size];

for (int a : myArray) {
    System.out.print(a);
    System.out.print(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char n = stringNum.charAt(i);
        int intNum = Character.getNumericalValue(n);
        myArray[i] = intNum;
    }
}
```

// input: 12345
// output: 0 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up printing the array and populating the array.

First, parse the input string and populate the array

```
String stringNum = input.nextLine();
int size = stringNum.length();
int[] myArray = new int[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    char n = stringNum.charAt(i);
    int intNum = Character.getNumericalValue(n);
    myArray[i] = intNum;
}
```

Then print the elements,

```
for (int a : myArray) {
    System.out.print(a);
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```